# Which is faster update or insert in MongoDB and WHY?

Tags: mongodb

Which query is faster in MongoDB insert query or update query and why that query was faster.

```
    db.collection.insert(
       <document or array of documents>
)
```

or

```
  db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the document which we are updating or inserting

> Insert:

Need to check whether the document of same _id is already exists

```
if document with same _id exists 
   then insert failed
else 
   insert document
```

> Update(with Upsert):

```
if document with same _id exists 
   update document
else 
   insert new document
```

Insert or Update will be taking same time when we have the document _id provided on the query and other factors such as Indexes we have in the collection also have considerable impact on the query [write performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-performance/). If a document _id is not provided in insert or update query then it will be slower

You can have a look on these references if you need to improve the performance of your mongodb

https://www.sitepoint.com/7-simple-speed-solutions-mongodb/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-performance/